# Django migration drops and re-adds same constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

Asking for a friend... Can anybody explain why my Django migration is dropping and re-adding the exact same constraint on my table column when I add `blank=True` to the model field?  Here's my change in my model:

```
# old definition
class CatalogCourse(models.Model):
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogSubject, related_name="catalog_course_set")

# new definition with `blank=True`
class CatalogCourse(models.Model):
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogSubject, related_name="catalog_course_set", blank=True)
```

When I `makemigrations`, I get this migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('homepage', '0005_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='catalogcourse',
            name='subjects',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='catalog_course_set', to='homepage.CatalogSubject'),
        ),
    ]
```

The SQL for this migration is simply:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field subjects on catalogcourse
--
ALTER TABLE "homepage_catalogcourse_subjects" DROP CONSTRAINT "homepa_catalogsubject_id_304824f4_fk_homepage_catalogsubject_id";
ALTER TABLE "homepage_catalogcourse_subjects" ADD CONSTRAINT "homepa_catalogsubject_id_304824f4_fk_homepage_catalogsubject_id" FOREIGN KEY ("catalogsubject_id") REFERENCES "homepage_catalogsubject" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE "homepage_catalogcourse_subjects" DROP CONSTRAINT "homepage_catalogcourse_id_cc699e39_fk_homepage_catalogcourse_id";
ALTER TABLE "homepage_catalogcourse_subjects" ADD CONSTRAINT "homepage_catalogcourse_id_cc699e39_fk_homepage_catalogcourse_id" FOREIGN KEY ("catalogcourse_id") REFERENCES "homepage_catalogcourse" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
COMMIT;
```

Is Django just built to drop a constraint and re-add it anytime we alter the field?  I can't think of any reason why that would need to happen? Are there operations that can't be performed while a foreign key constraint exists?

Comment: Why have you got many to many fields on both sides of the relationship? That is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: I don't... I'm showing you the old vs new field where the new one has blank=True and the old does not.  It's the same model.  I was just trying to convey that my change was minor and shouldn't have anything to do with the database definition of the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If looks like you are hitting the bug described in [ticket 25253](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25253).

Comment: Seems like this bug is still present in Django 2.1.3. Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Removing all the old migration files, dropping and re-creating the DB and calling makemigrations => migrate fixed the issue for me..

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot afford the downtime, use a ​[RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) migration operation with `state_operations` as a workaround. This will tell Django: running this SQL will be equivalent to these operations in terms of database state. Example:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
   """--
   -- Alter field trip on payment
   --
   ALTER TABLE "myapp_payment" ALTER COLUMN "trip_id" DROP NOT NULL;
   """,
   state_operations=[
       migrations.AlterField(
           model_name='payment',
           name='trip',
           field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True,
                                   on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT,
                                   related_name='payments', to='myapp.Trip'),
       ),
   ])
```

This way we only apply the SQL we want and Django won't complain about the migration state not matching the current model. :)